# Devise: Create user using only the Email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

How can I create a `Signup` using `Devise` where instead of the user entering both his `email` and `password` during sign up, all he needs to enter is an email and then get the `Password` generated through his email?

I'm trying to make sign up as simple as possible and I figured out that since devise is capable of sending out an activation email already, why not just piggy back on that and send a generated **Password** and confirm at the time of login?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: May this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up) will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Devise's **friendly token** in your controller:

```rb
password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
User.create(email: 'my@email.com', password: password, password_confirmation: password)
```

The **friendly_token** is a string containing **A-Z**, **a-z**, **0-9**, “**-”** and “**_**”.

Source code [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise.friendly_token):

```rb
def self.friendly_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(15).tr('lIO0', 'sxyz')
end
```

and [here](https://github.com/sj26/ruby-1.9.3-p0/blob/master/lib/securerandom.rb#L164) for more info:

```rb
def self.urlsafe_base64(n=nil, padding=false)
  s = [random_bytes(n)].pack("m*")
  s.delete!("\n")
  s.tr!("+/", "-_")
  s.delete!("=") if !padding
  s
end
```

Comment: This addresses assigning a password but doesn't touch on how to get the generated PW to the user and allow them to reset their account. In fact, i'm wondering if just signing the user up and sending them a PW recovering email would do it?

Comment: Oh ! I'm using the welcome email to send the generated password.